# Whence come "Alaskan" and "Hawaiian" as adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

Ross Douthat, writing in the *New York Times*, refers to "Rubio’s lonely Minnesotan triumph." This just sounds wrong to me. Is "Minnesotan" ever used as an adjective? Garrison Keillor frequently invokes ["Minnesota nice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_nice)—a phrase which seems to imply that the word for "of or pertaining to [State]" is "[State]."

See also "New York minute," *"California Dreamin,'"* "Oklahoma crude," *"Texas Chainsaw Massacre,"* etc.

On the other hand: "Alaskan king crab," "Hawaiian Punch." But I'm having a hard time coming up with other counter examples. It's pretty clear that Douthat's usage would require Rubio to **be** a Minnesotan to be correct.

Can anyone explain the reason for the "Alaskan" and "Hawaiian" anomalies?

Comment: Well, for Texas, you certainly have the well-established *Texan*, and *Minnesotan* is certainly plausible as an adjective, but clashes with the existing use as a demonym. I think it's be hard to adjectivize binomials like *New York*, as you'd have to recruit a hyphen or two.

Comment: Doesn't _Texan_ also clash with the existing use as a demonym? I mean, it seems like many states' demonyms are _plausible_ as adjectives, but only some of them sound right or are commonly used. "Alaskan king crab," but "Texas Toast."

Comment: Yes, that inconsistency also occurred to me after I posted my comment. My intuition is suggesting the "anomaly" isn't confined to AK and HI, but it's going to take a little more reflection on my part before I can make a case for it.

Comment: Consider Rome -> Roman, Egypt -> Egyptian, Georgia -> Georgian. There's no particular rule for which place-names get the 'ian' suffix for their residents, it's just those cases where it sounds right, and isn't considered too angular-sounding for common usage.

Comment: @Dan Bron: A little Ngram research puts _Texan_ and _Californian_ into the category of common adjectival use, but for _Louisianan_, similar to _Minnesotan_, none of the top ten variants of "Louisianan [_any word_]" constitute adjective modifying noun...

Comment: @AJFaraday: My curiosity isn't regarding which places get which demonymic suffixes. It's which demonyms seem also to be used as adjectives.

Comment: Well, you can certainly [speak Minnesotan](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/how-to-talk-minnesotan-howard-mohr/1103267969?ean=9781565114937&st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_Core+Shopping+Books_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP650&k_clickid=3x650), so it's not just a term for residents of the state.

Comment: @DaveM All of them. Hawiians = Hawiian people. It's already inherrently used as an adjective, so if you can describe a person as Hawaiian, you can describe anything else which is from or indicative of the place as hawaiian.

Comment: @Hot Licks: But _Minnesotan_ in that instance is, again, a noun.

Comment: @AJFaraday: Fair enough, but that doesn't really address the question of common usage. Further Ngram research adds _Kentuckian_ and _Ohioan_ to the list of those demonyms which appear to be little-used as adjectives.

Likewise _Montanan_.

Comment: @DaveM That's probably because they're quite awkward sounds, difficult to say, and harder to put into common usage.

Comment: @AJFarady: Maybe. But I personally find, say, "Californian legislature" to be no less awkward than "Minnesotan victory." (I know—subjective!)

Comment: Yeah, I cannot find in Ngram any apparent use of "Minnesotan" as an adjective for the state.  Though Ngram does not seen to find them, however, there are many uses of "Minnesotan" (as what is it called, an adjectival noun?) serving the purpose of an adjective for an attribute of a resident.

Comment: @DaveM - Is there any state for which "<this state>-ian legislature" doesn't sound awkward?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Well, "Georgian legislature" sounds pretty normal to me, but then "Georgian" as an adjective has a long and honorable life independent of its demonymic application, so I'm probably predisposed to hear it that way...

Comment: @DaveM - Yep, "Georgian legislature" seems to be the oddball.  "Kentuckian legislature", eg, is a no-show in NGram, as is "Iowan" and several other states I tried.  (Don't even want to think about "New Yorkian" and "New Jerseyan".)